# My DVD-ROM doesn't read anything and it is not shown in Device manager. What to do?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, device-manager

Suddenly my LG DVD-ROM stopped working. the bulb is blinking when i put DVD/CD in it, but nothing else happens. I can't see it in Device Manager either. What  to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar - and I bought a new one.

I would check the sata/IDE cable though.